# Keyboard shortcut to move Window to next Desktop?

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook-pro, desktop, multitasking

I would like a keyboard shortcut to do either of these actions :

- Move a 'focused' window to another desktop
- Create a new desktop and move the window to it, then change the view to that desktop

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only application I've found that supports that on 10.8 is [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/). It doesn't create new spaces though.

[image]

[Spacey](http://most-advantageous.com/spacey/) stopped working in 10.7

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/BetterTouchTool.zip)?

Comment: Yeah but couldn't find such action.